# How can I preload a sound?

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio

I have an iPhone app where I play a sound when the user is taking a test.  Works great except for the first time the sound plays when there is a delay, I assume loading the sound into memory.  How can I preload the sound?  Here is my code for the sound:

```
- (void)doBuzz:(id)sender {
SystemSoundID buzzsoundID;
NSString *buzzsoundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"buzz" ofType:@"caf"];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)
                                 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:buzzsoundFile]
                                 , &buzzsoundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(buzzsoundID);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my sound delay problem by moving my declaration for the SystemSoundID into the .h file of my UIViewController and then set the NSString and called AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID from ViewDidLoad.  Then when I wanted to play the sound, rather than calling the doBuzz method I simply replaced that with AudioServicesPlaySystemSound.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `AVAudioPlayer`, which you can setup and re-use. But more importantly, when you set it up, you can tell it to "prepare to play", which pre-loads the sound into memory. So when you actually tell the player to play, it plays immediately. I conveniently, recently wrote this method for something,  which creates and returns an `AVAudioPlayer` object:

```
+(AVAudioPlayer *)playerForFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData error:&error] autorelease];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"error creating player for %@: %@", fileName, [error localizedDescription]);

    return (error ? nil : player);
}
```

Somewhere in your app you might setup a player object like so:

```
AVAudioPlayer *buzzSoundPlayer = [MyClass playerForFile:@"buzz"];
if (buzzSoundPlayer) {
    [buzzsoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```

When you want to play the sound:

```
[buzzSoundPlayer setCurrentTime:0];
[buzzSoundPlayer play];
```

You have to set the current time to 0, i.e. the beginning of the sound file, each time you play it because when the sound finishes playing, the "current time" is at the end. So subsequent requests to play it would play nothing. So we set the current time back to the beginning.

You can setup a `delegate` for your player too, and be notified via a delegate method when a sound finishes playing. You could reset the current time to 0 there, alternatively.

You can read all about `AVAudioPlayer`, and `AVFoundation`, in Apple's documentation.

Comment: This doesn't actually pre-load the sound, it only enables you to re-use the same player (which is good). But, the first time the sound is played, you still get a delay.

Answer (score -1):

Preload the sound using `performSelectorInBackground:@selector(<SELECTOR>)`.

You also could load file on application start or somewhere before, not actually on touch.

Comment: I definitely want to load at application start.  Thanks for your info.  However, pardon my ignorance, but I don't understand your answer.  What would the SELECTOR be?